# Database Relational Design for Multiple Categories

Tags: database-design, ms-access, relational-theory

I am building a database for participants who are grouped into studies. There's a total of 5 different studies - A, B, C, D, and E. The participants may be in more than one studies, and participants within each study has a unique "study code" with different formats depending on the study is in. (i.e. Study A's code may be 10 characters with digits and alphabets, Study B's code may be only 6 characters digits only...etc)

I know that I need a many-to-many link table, and a look-up table for the studies, but other than that I am having a hard time figuring out where to incorporate the "study code" within the tables.

Here are the fields I have so far for my tables.

- Participants: participantID (primary key), name, date-of-birth...etc (background demographics)
- PatientInStudies: participantID, study, study_code
- LookupStudies: study(listing all the studies A, B, C..etc.)

Basically, the PatientInStudies table will look something like:

1, A, A123456789

1, B, 123456

1, C, BB23-1-52

2, A, A295890100

2, B, 123908

3, C, KG19-7-23....etc

Will the PatientInStudies Table work? Is there a better way to organize the study code within the database?

Thanks!

Comment: I'd add a constraint on the PatientInStudies table to prevent duplicate records, but otherwise it looks fine.

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner could you elaborate on what you mean by constraint? I am still learning Access and relational database design, thanks!

Comment: Constraints: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database#Constraints You should make a primary composite key of all three fields in this table to avoid duplicate records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I second @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner's suggestions for a unique constraint.  See http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/create-a-constraint-adp-HP003088257.aspx for how to do this in MS Access.

What a Unique Constraint does is state that no two rows can have duplicate data on some portion of the row.  So presumably you want each patient to be in a study only once, so you'd want a unique constraint on PatientsInStudy(participantID, study).

This way each individual can only be given one study id.  Similarly in that design your PatientsInStudy table would have a primary key spanning all three fields, and a second unique constraint on (StudyID, study_code).  This way even if two studies end up with similar semantics or overlapping spaces, the key cannot be reused in the same study.

Otherwise, good.